# jQuery click event target padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am trying to register clicks using jQuery and there seems to be an issue with the padding.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/claydiffrient/UCwAt/2/) to help with seeing it.

I'm trying to get clicks on an open menu to do nothing while clicks anywhere else will close all the menus.  It works well, but the biggest problem is if you click above the `<li>` but still within the `<div>` it fails.  It seems to be that the padding isn't counted as part of the div or something.

The code is here as well:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#mainMenu" class="menuLink">Main</a>
<div id="mainMenu" class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">item 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">item 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a href="#menuTwo" class="menuLink">Menu 2</a>

<div id="menuTwo" class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">item 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">item 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Attach a handler to the document for clicks.
    $(document).on("click", function (e) {
        //Get the click's target and convert to $ object.
        $target = $(e.target);
        //Find out if the click occurred on a menu.
        $parents = $target.parents(".menu");
        if ($parents.length > 0) {
            console.log(["Menu click", e]);
            return;
        } else {
            //If it wasn't on a menu close the open menu.
            console.log(["Non-menu click", e]);
            $('.menu').hide();
        }
    });

    //Handle showing the menu.
    $('.menuLink').on("click", function (e) {
        //Close all other menus.
        $('.menu').hide();
        console.log("Started");
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var targetMenu = $(e.target).attr("href");
        $(targetMenu).show();
    });
```

});

**CSS**

```
#mainMenu {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#menuTwo {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.menu {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
$parents = $target.parents(".menu");
```

Change it to this:

```
$parents = $target.closest(".menu");
```

The div doesn't have a parent with the class `.menu`, so if you click that, it doesn't find anything. `closest` includes the selected element in the search.

http://jsfiddle.net/ecnGr/

Comment: although this solves the issue, it doesn't cut down the unnecessary jungle in `$(document).on("click",...)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest` to solve your issue

```
$parents = $target.closest(".menu");
```

If you still want to use `parents` then add an extra check to see if the clicked element is the div.

```
if ($parents.length > 0 || $target.is('.menu')) {
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/UCwAt/3/)**

The problem with your code was that `parents` method does not include the element in question. So you have to do that check explicitly, or use `closest` which includes the `element` in question as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just consume all clicks on the menu, which will do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Attach a handler to the document for clicks.
    $(document).on("click", function (e) {
        $('.menu').hide();
    });

    $('.menuLink').on("click", function (e) {
        $('.menu').hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var targetMenu = $(e.target).attr("href");
        $(targetMenu).show();
    });

    //Handle showing the menu.
    $('.menu').on("click", function (e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MightyPork/UCwAt/8/