# Why does clicking on the padding of an element's child makes the element the event.target?

Tags: javascript

I've thought it can not happen. Is there a well-known reason, that I'm not aware of, or is it a Chrome bug? It happens in Chrome DevTools when device mode is on. Steps to reproduce:

1. [Open the demo](http://www.bolvari.hu/public/so36050353.html).
2. Open DevTools in Chrome (F12).
3. Enable device mode (CTRL+SHIFT+M).
4. **Reload the page (F5)** to see the mobile style scroll bars.
5. Click the right edge of the red child div to see "parent" instead "child".

If the demo is unavailable, here is the full code (doesn't work as a snippet):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style>

        #parent {
      background: yellow;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: auto
    }
    #child {
      background: red;
      height: 250px;
    }


</style>
</head>
<body>

     <div id="parent">
      <div id="child"></div>
    </div>

<script>

      document.querySelector('#parent').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      alert(event.target.id);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a place where we can see all of the code?  It's hard to diagnose without the complete picture.  Perhaps a JSFiddle?

Comment: *Tried to insert a demo, but it works fine here.* You should still include the code to reproduce, even if it means we have to put the code elsewhere for actual testing. Just be sure to include the conditions necessary for testing (browser, version, device, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which element you want to trigger for the event.

You can try switching to margin instead of padding so that there is a *margin* between the elements instead of padding of the child element.

You can also try looking at the event.currentTarget to see if that is what you intended to capture.

This other [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259829/jquery-click-event-target-padding) may help as it includes a JSFiddle example.

A helpful diagram can be the box model for understanding the zones around an element:
[image]

Comment: Why? What is the effect of doing this? How does that even answer the question? (*"Why does clicking on the padding of an element's child makes the element the event.target?"*)

Comment: If I were clicking on the child's margin, I wouldn't be surprised to see the parent element as the target. But now I'm clicking on the padding area (double checked in DevTools), so I expect the target to be the child, not the parent. Checking the currentTarget shows 'DIV', maybe becase there is an opacity:0 element with pointer-events:none above all the other elements. Checked the mentioned question, but I think that's something different.

Comment: If you want to capture the click on the LI in your example page, why not switch `document.querySelector('#termekek')` to: `document.querySelector('#termekek li')` ?

Comment: Good idea, but I need all the LI clicks. And as far as I know, it's not recommended to do `var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#termekek li'); for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) lis[i].addEventListener('click', function(){});`, because too much listeners could kill the weaker browsers. Instead it's recommended to use an "umbrella" listener, or whatever it's called.

Comment: And even if I was using individual listeners, I guess the padding would still not be treated the way it should: as part of the element. (Haven't tested.)

Comment: An umbrella listener is generally a good idea.  Will you have that many LIs where this could be an issue?  Try timing it using your data and `console.time()` to see the impact.

Comment: And for the record, in your example, when I click on the padding of your LI, I receive the LI as the event.target.  When I click on the white space to the right of the P tag, I get the P as the event.target.  If you want the P's area to the right, make the P tag `display:inline` or use a `span`.

Comment: I'll measure and adapt. Are you in device mode and still see LI when clicking on the LI's right padding? Strange, I see UL. (My Chrome version: 49.0.2623.87 m (64-bit)). I've thought you see the problem as well, but it might be a local problem. I'll try without Chrome extensions.

Comment: Ps. don't forget to reload in device mode, so that the scroll bars disappear.

Comment: Ugh, the scroll bars... I've figured it out, see my answer in a minute.

Comment: I would prefer it if you edited this answer and accepted rather than posting your own one liner, especially after all of the time :-/

Comment: I think the one liner answers the question, but you really deserve those points after your help that I appriciate. Is it okay if I edit your answer by removing everything you wrote, and paste the one liner instead? (I think your original answer was helpful to investigate the issue, but in it's current form it's irrelevant, because it turned out that there is no padding-margin problem, just a scrollbar thing.) Can I totally reedit and accept that?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a hidden scroll bar, that belongs to the parent element.